# Is there R library or way to draw sigmoid function and get equation from raw data

Tags: r, sigmoid

[image]

This plot means drugs Concentration.

And I want to change this plot like sigmoid plot which is a curve.

[raw data]

```r
μM <- c(0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30)
log_μM <- log(c(0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30))
DMSO <- c(97.01, 98.43, 98.29, 97.66, 96.51, 88.39, 38.54, 2.63) # D137
log_DMSO <- log(c(97.01, 98.43, 98.29, 97.66, 96.51, 88.39, 38.54, 2.63))
```

The raw data is small, but I want to express it well, and get the R-Square value.

Comment: I believe there are two issues with your request. First, your data isn't a true binary, so you can't fit a logistic regression curve like the sigmoid function, only some type of nonlinear regression. The other issue is with R2. Given this has a nonlinear function, which R2 are you looking for?

Comment: I want to find an equation that is most similar to the data.
If it's not sigmoid, I want to draw a plot like an exponential function, and I want to find the R-Square value to see if the green plot and data are similar.
Is it impossible because the data is too small?

Comment: Green plot? I only see a red plot here.

Comment: Oh, There was a translation problem.  
Not green plot, It's drawed plot.  
sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the original (**not** log-log) scale, a sigmoid curve turns out to be a good fit.

```r
## pack data into a data frame (best practice)
dd <- data.frame(μM, DMSO)
## fit with "self-starting 4-parameter logistic model"
fit <- nls(DMSO ~ SSfpl(μM, l_asy, r_asy, xmid, scal), data = dd)
## plot:
par(las = 1, bty = "l") ## cosmetic
plot(DMSO ~ μM, data = dd)  ## points
mvec <- seq(min(μM), max(μM), length.out = 101)
pvec <-predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(μM = mvec))
lines(mvec, pvec)
```

[image]

If you want to plot this on a log-log scale, just add `log = "xy"` to the `plot()` command, but note that the plot won't **look** sigmoidal:

[image]

The `?SSfpl` web page gives the equation

```
l_asy+(r_asy-l_asy)/(1+exp((xmid-μM)/scal))
```

`coef(fit)` will give you the estimated coefficients.

As for R^2: you can calculate an R^2 value via `1-mean(residuals(fit)^2)/var(μM)` (I think — the second term might be off by  factor of n/(n-1) or so because `var()` uses `n-1` in the denominator ...) but there's [lots](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/r-squared-invalid-nonlinear-regression) [of](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551915/interpreting-nonlinear-regression-r2) [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185275/how-to-measure-the-goodness-of-fit-of-a-nonlinear-model-is-r2-useful?noredirect=1&lq=1) (which you should read!) about why you might not want to/why it might not mean what you think it means ...

PS: it's a nuisance to have a variable name (`μM`) that can't easily be typed on a plain keyboard — might want to reconsider that choice ...

Comment: But at original scale, the data is too crowded.
I try again :)
And I try to check variable name.

Comment: See edits .....